# Maven: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I'm trying to build jar for Kotlin project with `maven-assembly-plugin` but it complains.

The project itself is a standard Kotlin project with `src` dir and some maven dependencies.

The errror:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) on project ib_api: 
Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.
```

For this `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin configuration.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

P.S.

The full log

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/alex/projects/ib_api "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=57323:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.2 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< al6x:ib_api >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building ib_api 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) @ ib_api ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.751 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-18T21:24:03+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (default-cli) on project ib_api: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

And the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>al6x</groupId>
  <artifactId>ib_api</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.72</kotlin.version>
    <ktor.version>1.3.2</ktor.version>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    <main.class>AppKt</main.class>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The config for maven-assembly-plugin is wrong,  is in wrong place, it should be

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Please use a more recent version of maven-assembly-plugin see here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/